# JQuery mobile loading display

Tags: jquery-mobile

I created a loading display method like so

```
function customShowLoading(text){
    $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
      text: text,
      textVisible: true,
      theme: 'e',
      html: ''
    });
}

customShowLoading("Some message");
```

Every time the loading display shows, it just says 'loading' for its text
instead of the passed in parameter message. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching the "text" variable to another name? It could be some variable name overlap.

Comment: Weird. What jQuery Mobile and jQuery Core versions are you using?

Comment: Jquery 1.10 and Jquery mobile 1.4.2

Comment: I can't say what is failing then. I just tried with your code and those versions you mention (jQ 1.10.2 + jQM 1.4.2), added the customShowLoading method to a <script> tag and then invoked it from a button click, it worked for me.

Comment: May be, if you can provide your HTML (if possible) I could take a look and see if I can point out something that could be wrong at first glance.